# Permissions error setting recovery option with changeserviceconfig2

Tags: delphi, service

I'm installing a service and wanting to set the service recovery options (using admin in an XP environment). I can change the description happily enough, but if the sfa.cActions is anything but zero it fails with a error 87 (parameter error).

```
//
// Actions to take on service failure
//
  {$EXTERNALSYM _SC_ACTION_TYPE}
  _SC_ACTION_TYPE = (SC_ACTION_NONE, SC_ACTION_RESTART, SC_ACTION_REBOOT, SC_ACTION_RUN_COMMAND);
  {$EXTERNALSYM SC_ACTION_TYPE}
  SC_ACTION_TYPE = _SC_ACTION_TYPE;

  PServiceAction = ^TServiceAction;
  {$EXTERNALSYM _SC_ACTION}
  _SC_ACTION = record
    aType : SC_ACTION_TYPE;
    Delay : DWORD;
  end;
  {$EXTERNALSYM SC_ACTION}
  SC_ACTION = _SC_ACTION;
  TServiceAction = _SC_ACTION;


procedure TXyz_Service_Module.SetDescription(const Desc: ansistring);
var
  hSCM: SC_HANDLE;
  hService: SC_HANDLE;
  sd: SERVICE_DESCRIPTION;
begin
  hSCM := WinSvc.OpenSCManager(nil, nil, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
  if hSCM = 0 then Exit;
  hService := WinSvc.OpenService(hSCM, PChar(Self.Name), SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG);
  if hService = 0 then Exit;
  sd.lpDescription := PAnsiChar(Desc);
  ChangeServiceConfig2(hService, SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION, @sd);
  WinSvc.CloseServiceHandle(hService);
  WinSvc.CloseServiceHandle(hSCM);
end;

procedure TXyz_Service_Module.SetRecovery;
var
  hSCM: SC_HANDLE;
  hService: SC_HANDLE;
  sfa: SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONS;
  actions: array [0 .. 2] of SC_ACTION;
begin
  hSCM := WinSvc.OpenSCManager(nil, nil, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
  if hSCM = 0 then Exit;
  hService := WinSvc.OpenService(hSCM, PChar(Self.Name), SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);
  if hService = 0 then Exit;

  sfa.dwResetPeriod := 999; //INFINITE;
  sfa.lpCommand := nil;
  sfa.lpRebootMsg := nil;
  sfa.cActions := 1;
  sfa.lpsaActions := @actions[0];

  actions[0].aType := SC_ACTION_RESTART;
  actions[0].Delay := 5000;
  (*actions[1].aType := SC_ACTION_RESTART;
  actions[1].Delay := 5000;
  actions[2].aType := SC_ACTION_RESTART;
  actions[2].Delay := 5000;*)

  if not changeserviceconfig2(hservice,SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS,@sfa) then begin
     showmessage('Error : '+inttostr(getlasterror));
  end;
  WinSvc.CloseServiceHandle(hService);
  WinSvc.CloseServiceHandle(hSCM);
end;

procedure TXyz_Service_Module.ServiceAfterInstall(Sender: TService);
begin
  self.SetDescription('Bananas are yellow');
  self.SetRecovery;
end;
```

Comment: Go read the API doc for changeserviceconfig2 again. It notes what is needed. It is the reason for your failure.

Comment: Changed to SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS, which changed the error. Restated the question.

Comment: BTW, your code leaks `hSCM` if `OpenService()` fails.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`ChangeServiceConfig2()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681988.aspx) documentation:

> hService [in]
>   A handle to the service. This handle is returned by the `OpenService` or `CreateService` function and **must have the `SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG` access right**. For more information, see [Service Security and Access Rights](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685981.aspx).
>
> If the service controller handles the `SC_ACTION_RESTART` action, hService **must have the SERVICE_START access right**.

So, `SetRecovery()` will need to use this at a minimum:

```
hService := WinSvc.OpenService(hSCM, PChar(Self.Name), SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG or SERVICE_START);
```

Comment: Opening the service to change the recovery options I use SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS which is $F01FF and has those bits set. Using SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG or SERVICE_START leaves me with the same 87 error. If there is a permission error - which I was getting earlier for the reason you describe - the error code is 5.

Comment: `SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS` has other bits set that the caller may or may not have permissions to use. `SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS` is generally only usable by admin users. Always ask for the minimum permissions that you actually need, don't ask for what you don't need. Error 5 is a permissions error, but error 87 means you are not passing in the correct data to begin with.

Comment: Yes, I'd figured that much but couldn't see where the error could be. By comparing the bytes from a QueryServiceConfig2 I found the issue was the way the enumeration was saved into a 4 byte block but only 1 byte was written. I'd checked the size of record but the byte alignment behaviour hid it.

Answer (score 0):

It's the enumeration value.

```
 _SC_ACTION_TYPE = (SC_ACTION_NONE, SC_ACTION_RESTART, SC_ACTION_REBOOT, SC_ACTION_RUN_COMMAND);
```

needs to be

```
{$MinEnumSize=4}
 _SC_ACTION_TYPE = (SC_ACTION_NONE, SC_ACTION_RESTART, SC_ACTION_REBOOT, SC_ACTION_RUN_COMMAND);
```

As recommended in the comments by David Heffernan.

Comment: This is the wrong solution. The correct solution is to set the enum size to 4 in the unit that declares all the interop types. Add `{$MINENUMSIZE 4}` to the top of that unit. Or simply use `WinSvc` from the RTL and avoid trying to re-invent the wheel. We would have been able to help with this had your question included a [mcve].

Comment: Still finding my way around in here, thanks very much for your help.